# Error during CMake-generated for Make install: "file Internal CMake error when trying to open file: .../install_manifest.txt for writing."

Tags: cmake

I am repeatedly getting this error when I use `make install` or `sudo make install`:

```
file Internal CMake error when trying to open file:
  project_dir/install_manifest.txt for writing.
```

If I look into the cmake_install.cmake file, the offending lines are always here:

```
file(WRITE "project_dir/${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST}" "")
foreach(file ${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_FILES})
  file(APPEND "project_dir/${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST}" "${file}\n")
endforeach()
```

So I guess the problem is permissions? But I am running with sudo so I don't understand how that could be an issue.

Comment: No it does not have to be in root. That was just the syntax I wrote when creating a minimal example. I just edited the original post to make it more clear

Comment: It isn't a special character, `<project dir>` is just a variable name. I'm using cmake 2.8.12 on Mac OS X Yosemite (though this was happening before on Mavericks)

Comment: Sorry for being confusing... Those brackets are common as variables when speaking of directories. `project_dir` is simply a directory name I used to simplify my problem. In reality it's probably more like /home/user/dir or something of that nature

Comment: Does the file already exist?  In Windows I've gotten similar errors when an output file is in use, such as open in an editor or an executable file is running.   In InstallShield I've had file explorer open on a folder it wanted to delete and re-create.